# java static import compilation error

Tags: java

Using java version 1.7.0_05

When i compile the below code it's give me testpackage could not be found error.

But if i remove the static keyword from "import static testpackage.TestStatic;" it's compiling successfully.

**Test:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import static testpackage.TestStatic;
import static java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE;

public class Test  {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
        System.out.println("Maximum value of int variable using " +  
                "static import : "
                + MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

**TestStatic:**

```
package testpackage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestStatic  {

    public static void testStatic() {
        System.out.println("Inside Test Static");
    }
    public void testNormal(){
        System.out.println("test normal");  
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything you said is true. What are you asking and/or complaining about?

Comment: import static testpackage.TestStatic.*;

Or perhaps just import what you need, e.g.,:
import static testpackage.TestStatic.testStatic;
import static testpackage.TestStatic.main;

Comment: Didn't your IDE gave you the above two options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

import static is for importing static *members* of classes, not whole classes.  You could say "import static testpackage.TestStatic.testStatic;".

EDIT: fixed syntax

Comment: It is `import static testpackage.TestStatic.testStatic;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  If i want to import the class as well as static methods and fields do i need to have two import statements?  import static testpackage.TestStatic.*; import testpackage.*;

Comment: Maybe so. I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly -- if you just do "import testpackage.TestStatic" you get access to the whole class, static and dynamic members alike.  In that case you'll have to refer to TestStatic's members as "TestStatic.testStatic()" rather than just "testStatic()", but that seems less confusing than trying to import the static members twice.  (But, as for what would technically happen, I don't know; you're probably right -- try it and see!)

Answer (score 1):

When you say `import static testpackage.TestStatic;` the compiler does not know what you want to import, you could mean import a static variable `TestStatic` in a class `testpackage`. In fact, I think you wanted to import `testStatic()` from the `testpackage.TestStatic` class,

*For a method or field by name*

```
import static testpackage.TestStatic.testStatic;
```

*For all static methods and fields*

```
import static testpackage.TestStatic.*;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  If i want to import the class as well as static methods and fields do i need to have two import statements?  import static testpackage.TestStatic.*; import testpackage.*;